Get Observable Plot x,y data values from mouse (hover) position

Question: How can I get the x/y data values from an Obervable Plot for the point the mouse is hovering over? (Or touched on mobile.)
Background: I am trying to make an interactive timeline like on https://merrysky.net. So I would like to convert the mouse's X position to the time/temperature value from the data that has been plotted.
Current progress:

Live demo
Relevant (Observable Plot) code



Currently, the red rule on the plot reactively updates (try playing/dragging the radar timeline.)
The next task is to reactively update in the other direction: the time and temperature data that is displayed at the very top change when the mouse hovers over the temperature plot. (The red rule should follow the mouse pointer and the appropriate data should be updated.)


I have examined the Observable Plot documentation. There seems to be API's for updating certain marks when the pointer is near them, but I could not see anything for extracting data from the plot based on mouse position. The Crosshair mark seems to be the closest to what I am looking for.
Perhaps the underlying D3 API must be used?

can you try to add the mouse event on the SVG and then use those coordinate to convert it into data coordinates? check https://jsfiddle.net/Lum5fxg1/

For straight d3, here's a very similar effect I wrote up, jeez, 8 years ago...

Wow, Observable Plot is extremely cool.  Looks like you can completely replicate your target (and what I did 8 years ago) as easy as:
const plot = Plot.plot({
  marks: [
    // draw the line graph
    Plot.line(data, { x: 'x', y: 'y' }),
    // add vertical interaction line
    Plot.ruleX(data, Plot.pointerX({ x: 'x', py: 'y', stroke: 'red' })),
    // add interaction dot
    Plot.dot(data, Plot.pointerX({ x: 'x', y: 'y', stroke: 'red' })),      
    // add interaction text
    Plot.text(
      data,
      Plot.pointerX({
        x: 'x',
        y: 'y',
        dx: 20,
        text: 'y',
      })
    ),
  ],
});

Running example:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="myplot"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/plot@0.6"></script>
<script type="module">
  const data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    data.push({
      x: i,
      y: Math.random() * 100,
    });
  }

  const plot = Plot.plot({
    marks: [
      Plot.line(data, { x: 'x', y: 'y' }),
      Plot.ruleX(data, Plot.pointerX({ x: 'x', py: 'y', stroke: 'red' })),
      Plot.dot(data, Plot.pointerX({ x: 'x', y: 'y', stroke: 'red' })),
      Plot.text(
        data,
        Plot.pointerX({
          x: 'x',
          y: 'y',
          dx: 20,
          text: 'y',
        })
      ),
    ],
  });

  const div = document.querySelector('#myplot');
  div.append(plot);
</script>



-- Edits based on comment --
How about something like this.  It provides an entry point to the plot so you can only tear down and recreate what you need:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="myplot"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/plot@0.6"></script>
<script type="module">
  const div = document.querySelector('#myplot');

  const data1 = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    data1.push({
      x: i,
      y: Math.random() * 100,
    });
  }

  const plot1 = Plot.ruleX([0], {
    render: (i, s, v, d, c, next) => {
      const g = next(i, s, v, d, c);
      c.ownerSVGElement.updateRuleX = (value) => {
        const pg = d3.select('g');
        pg.select('.custom-rule').remove();

        const ig = pg.append('g')
          .attr('class','custom-rule');
        
        ig.append('line')
          .attr('x1', s.x(value))
          .attr('x2', s.x(value))
          .attr('y1', s.y.range()[0])
          .attr('y2', s.y.range()[1])
          .attr('stroke', 'red');

        ig.append('circle')
          .attr('r', 5)
          .attr('stroke', 'red')
          .attr('cx', s.x(value))
          .attr('cy', s.y(data1[value].y));
      };
    },
  }).plot({
    marks: [
      Plot.line(data1, {x: 'x', y: 'y'}),
      Plot.ruleX(data1, Plot.pointerX({ x: 'x', py: 'y', stroke: 'red' })),
      Plot.dot(data1, Plot.pointerX({ x: 'x', y: 'y', stroke: 'red' })),
      Plot.text(
        data1,
        Plot.pointerX({
          x: 'x',
          y: 'y',
          dx: 20,
          text: 'y',
        })
      ),
    ],
  });
  div.append(plot1);

  const updateRuleExternal = () => {
    const v = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1) + 1);
    plot1.updateRuleX(v)
  };
  setInterval(updateRuleExternal, 500);

</script>




Yes! I found Plot.pointerX after I posted my question. It even has plot.addEventListener() so elements outside the plot can be updated. However, your solution is still missing one piece: updating the red rule based on external events. (Notice https://merrysky.net has multiple red rules on multiple plots and they are all connected, displaying the same time). I was able to make my red rule reactive like this, but it requires repeatedly destroying and creating new plots: https://github.com/Leftium/weather-sense/blob/2946961cb3128f652ccc07117bf7aaf16f3e1739/src/routes/TimeLine.svelte#L46-L90

Perhaps I can use a combination of your solution and my solution: A permanent plot like yours, plus another plot overlaid on top with just the red rule when the mouse is outside the plot. Then only the extra simpler plot has to be destroyed and created again when the red rule needs to be updated. Any better ideas? Ideally a Plot.ruleX mark could be added and removed dynamically.

@Leftium, see edit above.  Based on this example there is a way to hook the internals and update the plot.  Although, to be honest, with so much customization (perhaps fragile customization when the library revs), I'm curious what Observable.plot is really providing.  You could just do the whole thing in straight d3.

Wow, thanks~ Your method in the edit is much cleaner than what I hoped for. (Answer accepted!) My final weather timeline will be more complex than the example in this question, but mostly static. I think the red rule is the only thing that needs to be done via d3. Doing the whole thing in d3 may be the way to go, but I'm not familiar with d3. Observable.plot  seemed more approachable and got me 90% there.

I adapted this answer for my specific problem, with some various fixes/enhancements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78595834/117030 Again, thanks!

Hey, I made some progress and opened a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78597528/117030

I just realized that if scales  can be generated outside the plot, updateRuleX() can also be defined outside the plot, right?

Indeed, I was able to move updateRuleX() outside and remove that extra plot. Check out what I've achieved so far with your help: https://weather-sense.leftium.com

I have adapted Mark's answer for my application:

Live demo
Relevant source code

The radar timeline and plot are now mutually reactive:

Playing/dragging the radar timeline updates the plot
Hovering over the plot updates the radar timeline
(The date/time at the top is also updated)


Notable changes/improvements to Mark's answer:

Make selector more specific: pg = d3.select(div).select('g'). For some reason d3.select('g') did not work in my app (and the selector was too broad, selecting another svg on the page).
Don't append (render) red ruleX if value is outside plot's domain.
Return a value from render(). (Not needed, but fixes type error.)

Other major additions:

Use plot.addEventListener() to update variables and elements outside the plot.
Call plot.updateRuleX() in reaction to change in external variable.
Initially render blank placeholder and render plot after data has been loaded.
Rerender plot when containing element is resized.

