How to filter Observable Plot text mark when "section" is too narrow
Using Observable Plot, I wish to recreate the https://merrysky.net weather timeline with colored bands and text labels.
I have gotten an initial version working, but it has some flaws:

The labels are often longer than the "section" they are labeling, so the text overlaps with the next label.
The labels are not centered on the section. (I know how to fix this, except when adding icons to the left of the labels.)
Live demo
Relevant source code

Questions:

First of all: is there a better way to create these colored & labeled sections in Observable Plot? My code uses Plot.areaY
How do I filter out the labels that are too wide for their sections? Currently my code is a simple filter that removes repeated weather codes. The filter function has access to the data item, but the only information related to the X axis is time. I am not sure how to convert this time into pixels on the X axis. (Nor calculate the width of the label itself in pixels.)
Finally, I would like to add a small image mark of the weather code icon to the left of the text label. When the section is too narrow, only the icon would display (if there is enough width.)

Of course, I am open to solutions using the underlying D3 API, as well.

Screenshot of current progress:


UPDATE: added simple example:


const data = [{
    text: 'Heavy Freezing Drizzle',
    utc: new Date('2024-06-16'), end: new Date('2024-06-17'),
  }, {
    text: 'Light Snow Showers',
    utc: new Date('2024-06-17'), end: new Date('2024-06-18'),
  }, {
    text: 'Clear',
    utc: new Date('2024-06-18'), end: new Date('2024-06-22'),
  }, {
    text: 'Thunderstorms with light hail',
    utc: new Date('2024-06-22'), end: new Date('2024-06-23'),
  }]
  
  const plot = Plot.plot({
    height: 100,
    marks: [
        Plot.rectY(data, {
            x1: (d) => d.utc,
                x2: (d) => d.end,
                y: 1,
                fill: (d) => d.text == 'Clear' ? 'lightgray': 'SkyBlue'
            }),
      Plot.text(data, {
        x: (d) => (Number(d.utc) + Number(d.end))/2,
        text: 'text'
      }),
    ],
  });

  const div = document.querySelector('#myplot');
  div.append(plot);
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/plot@0.6"></script>

"Clear" is the only text mark that should be rendered because the other text marks overflow their section rect marks.


<div id="myplot"></div>




Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

You are essentially asking how to do overlap detection.  Here's a quick algorithm that I stuffed into the same style "render" method we used in your last question.  I've tried to comment it well:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="myplot"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/plot@0.6"></script>
<script type="module">
  const div = document.querySelector('#myplot');

  const codes = ['tiny', 'very, very, very, very, very, large'];
  const data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    data.push({
      x: i,
      y: Math.random() * 100,
      code: codes[Math.floor(Math.random() * codes.length)]  //<-- random label of varying size
    });
  }

  const plot = Plot.plot({
    marks: [
      Plot.text(data, {
        x: 'x',
        y: 100,
        textAnchor: 'start',
        text: function (d) {
          return d.code;
        },
        render: (i, s, v, d, c, next) => {
          const g = next(i, s, v, d, c),
            textLabels = d3.select(g).selectAll('text').nodes();
          setTimeout(() => {  //<-- run in setTimeout as we need the text elements to render to get their size
            for (let i = 0; i < textLabels.length - 1; i++) { //<-- loop the labels
              const cu = textLabels[i],
                cuBBox = cu.getBoundingClientRect();  //<-- get the size of the current label
              for (let j = i + 1; j < textLabels.length; j++) { //<-- loop the next N adjacent labels
                const ne = textLabels[j],
                  neBBox = ne.getBoundingClientRect();
                if (cuBBox.x + cuBBox.width > neBBox.x) {
                  d3.select(ne).remove();  //<-- if the adjacent label overlaps current, remove adjacent
                } else {
                  i = j - 1; //<-- we've found the first adjacent that doesn't overlap, return to top loop and let this one become our next "current"
                  break;
                }
              }
            }
          },0);

          return g;
        },
      }),
      Plot.line(data, { x: 'x', y: 'y' }),
    ],
  });
  div.append(plot);
</script>



Edits Based on Comments
Here's a modification that "ellipses" the text based on the size of the sibling rects.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/plot@0.6"></script>

"Clear" is the only text mark that should be rendered because the other text
marks overflow their section rect marks.

<div id="myplot"></div>

<script>
  const data = [
    {
      text: 'Heavy Freezing Drizzle',
      utc: new Date('2024-06-16'),
      end: new Date('2024-06-17'),
    },
    {
      text: 'Light Snow Showers',
      utc: new Date('2024-06-17'),
      end: new Date('2024-06-18'),
    },
    {
      text: 'Clear',
      utc: new Date('2024-06-18'),
      end: new Date('2024-06-22'),
    },
    {
      text: 'Thunderstorms with light hail',
      utc: new Date('2024-06-22'),
      end: new Date('2024-06-23'),
    },
  ];

  const plot = Plot.plot({
    height: 100,
    marks: [
      Plot.rectY(data, {
        x1: (d) => d.utc,
        x2: (d) => d.end,
        y: 1,
        fill: (d) => (d.text == 'Clear' ? 'lightgray' : 'SkyBlue'),
      }),
      Plot.text(data, {
        x: (d) => (Number(d.utc) + Number(d.end)) / 2,
        text: 'text',
        render: (i, s, v, d, c, next) => {
          const g = next(i, s, v, d, c);
          setTimeout(() => {
            const textLabels = d3.select(g).selectAll('text').nodes(),
              rects = d3.select(g.previousSibling).selectAll('rect').nodes();
            for (let i = 0; i < textLabels.length; i++) {
              const t = textLabels[i],
                r = rects[i],
                rW = r.getBBox().width;
              let txt = v.text[i],
                  tW = t.getComputedTextLength();
              while (tW > rW && txt.length > 0) {
                txt = txt.slice(0, -1);
                t.textContent = txt + "...";
                tW = t.getComputedTextLength();
              }              
            }
          }, 10);
          return g;
        },
      }),
    ],
  });

  const div = document.querySelector('#myplot');
  div.append(plot);
</script>




This doesn't take into account the section width in relation to the label width. I added a code snippet example to my question: only the "Clear" label should be rendered because the other labels don't fit their sections. (That's too bad if the only way to get the width of a text mark is to render it first... is there any way to just clip the text so it doesn't overflow its rect mark?)

Ideally text that is too long could be clipped with an ellipsis like: 'Heavy Freez...'

@Leftium, see edits above.  As far as the "That's too bad if the only way to get the width of a text mark" goes there are ways around that.  First, you could move all of this outside of the render function and simply do it as straight d3 after drawing the chart.  I avoided that as I like the encapsulation of doing this within the confines of the plot call.  Second, you could append a fake SVG to render the text and test its width, which you remove after the test.  Both of these solutions, though, are less elegant to me then the simple setTimeout I'm using.

Another great answer~ accepted! Also, check out the Observable Plot-based solution I came up with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78613628/117030

In addition to Mark's excellent solution, I found an Observable Plot-based solution:

Live demo
Relevant code

Pre-calculate data + props for rendering
Render data from above with Plot.text




First, use Plot.rect instead of Plot.Area. Plot.Area works, but its interpolation can cause strange output for this type of use case.
Render a special data array that merges adjacent data items with the same weather code into a single data item, so x1 is the starting time and x2 is the ending time for a section with that code.
While we're at it, calculate xMiddle to mark the middle of the section.
Sending this data to Plot.text() is pretty straight-forward.
Whether the section is too narrow could not be precalculated, so a function is used for the text property. Method plot.scale('x').apply() is used to convert time units to pixel units and helps determine if the section is too narrow.
I just hard-coded a width of 80 pixels (which works for my labels), but any of the methods Mark suggested could be used to calculate the exact width of the text.
There is a chicken-and-egg problem because plot = Plot.plot() needs to use plot.scale(). I hacked around this problem by calling plot() twice. If not called twice, the scaling doesn't work the first time. Thus the width check doesn't work and labels won't be hidden when the sections are too narrow.

